# How to autofill input data while using history.back() function?

Tags: javascript

On some computers the input data does not get an autofill, when going back with the function history.back().

```
<a class="backlink" href="javascript:history.back();">
```

When i click the Link, i want to go back to my configurator and the input data i added before should always get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Data is not preserved automatically when you go from one page to another.

Which technology you are using for Front End (i.e. angular, HTML5, PHP, ASP.Net, etc) to display data on the page?

The answer depends on that? Let's say, if you are using ASP.Net, then you have to store data in the `Session`.

Comment: I use PHP and html.twig, to display the data in the shop.

On some browsers the information is still displayed when i click on the Back-Function, and on some other browsers the fields are clean.